# Calling async action in asp.net core means file in formData is lost from c# API method

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, file-upload, form-data

I can read a file from the form-data and save it as expected. However, when I do an async action, the stream closes and the file is no longer there. Removing the async action means that it works again. I need to do an async query to save the file in the correct place.

```
    [Route("uploadFile")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public  async void uploadFile()
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

        if (files != null)
        {
            var file = files.FirstOrDefault();
            var fileName = file.FileName; 

            using (var input = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                  var id = "someId";
                  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                  // after doing this async action, the file and stream are no longer accessible. 
                  ...
```

Comment: the file, or the stream?  this doesn't seem to be related to DynamoDB per-se but more likely an issue with the async support in asp.net core: something to try -- instead of doing the DynamoDB query, try this: `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))` and see if this causes the same problem, in which case you can at least focus your efforts in the right direction

Comment: both the file and the stream. The file becomes null and the stream becomes closed. What a great idea! I tried this and confirmed that you are right, the issue is with async support in asp.net core. Thanks, I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a question to the asp.net core team and had an answer [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27288#issuecomment-717841864).

> Don't use async void in your controller action. Use async Task instead so that the framework can wait until you are done.

I didn't expect the return type to impact this functionality, but well, now I know.